# Windows 8 Pixel density large screen

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I have Windows 8 Media Center Edition running on an HTPC and would like to make the Metro icons 'larger' on my 62" 1080i TV.  I've found a [blog article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201195134/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx) that discusses how Windows determines pixel density based on resolution, however I do not see a way to change the default assigned values for my resolution via the UI.  I know this can be done as I saw a 2012 Build video where they demo'd a large screen touch display and mentioned that you can over-ride the pixel density via the registry, I just don't know what key.  Help anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Check this article:

[Adjusting Windows 8 display size/scaling for high DPI/PPI monitors](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3153/~/adjusting-windows-8-display-size/scaling-for-high-dpi/ppi-monitors)

1. right-click over the desktop and select Screen resolution
2. Select Make text and other items larger or smaller from the bottom
   of the display settings.
3. here, you can change the scaling for your display.

[image]

(image source: nvidia.custhelp.com)

Comment: This does not affect the tile size on the standard metro desktop.  I would like to have the tiles be larger, as they are not readable on a 62" screen at 1080i

Comment: ok. I haven't tried to connect my win8 to my tv.