# WIndows 8 Start/Metro scaling for big TVs

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, dpi, scaling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Pixel density large screen](https://superuser.com/questions/526756/windows-8-pixel-density-large-screen)

Is there any way to increase the Metro UI / Start elements size ?
I mean in the same way you can change the dpi scaling for the desktop mode (same as in other windows versions). It seems this wa spossible for the RC version of Windows8 but I'm talking about the release version.

I'm using Windows8 on my HTPC connected to a 1080p 47" TV. Using desktop apps is fine with scaling set to 200%, but this does not work for Metro Apps and the Metro menu, and the tiles and text is very tiny.